# Todays Ubuntu 22.04 updates seem to break Clang compiler

Tags: compiling, clang

After installing todays updates in my Ubuntu 22.04 machines compiling with Clang fails. Standard header files are not found anymore. E.g.
evaluate.cpp:19:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
Tested with two different applications that support Clang compilation (e.g.https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish ) and two different machines.

Edit: Will look at the update history later (no time now) but while updating I saw a package "cpp-12" being installed/updated. This is probably gcc-12 and maybe it mixes some header files that are also used by Clang. Just a guess...

Edit2: Meanwhile I removed cpp-12 (which also removed nvidia-dkms packages) but no luck. Clang still doesn't find standard headers.

Edit3: Installing g++-12 did it. Clang compilations works again.

Comment: "today's updates" is vague. Review your /var/log/apt/history.log to see *exactly* which packages were upgraded and when. If you are unsure which packages might be responsible for the problem, then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1441844/edit) to include the list of packages.

Comment: Also seeing this issue with clang after the update "gcc-12:amd64 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04". Removing gcc-12 as suggested below is not possible because dkms depends on it. Currently stuck unable to build any of our software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing g++-12, which in turn installs libstdc++-12-dev appears to fix the issue.

clang-14 depends on libgcc-11-dev and libstdc++-11-dev though so not sure why this worked.

Comment: That helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find Stack Exchange's policy on cross-posting answers (there is a little something [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296125)), but I wrote [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605488/3068259) that is actually a direct answer to the question. I won't copy paste it since I might edit it, and I don't want to edit in two different places.

Answer (score 0):

Removing gcc-12 and cpp-12 followed by autoremove helped. It's not exactly a solution, though.